# ASP.NET :- Deleting records from two tables using single view

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to delete data from 2 tables. I am using entity framework.

Here is the class .

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(int employeeId)
        {
            int id = employeeId;
            MvcWebApp.DbModel.profile profile = dbContext.profiles.Find(employeeId);
            dbContext.profiles.Remove(profile);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
            regi regi = dbContext.regis.Find(id);
            dbContext.regis.Remove(regi);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Where `employeeId` is the Column name of child table and `Id` is column name of parent table .

`MvcWebApp.DbModel.profile` This is fully qualified name of class.

I am getting `profile` object null.

Comment: ASP.NET is a web framework, it doesn't read or delete data. Are you asking about Entity Framework? Why are you calling `SaveChanges` twice, instead of calling `Remove` as needed and only calling `SaveChanges in the end?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Beacause I need save changes of 2 tables.

Comment: That's not what `SaveChanges` does - it persists *all* changes since the last time it was called. You only need to call it once. Besides, EF deals with entities, not tables. If there's a parent/child relation with `DeleteBehavior.Cascade`, deleting the parent will delete the children when `SaveChanges` is called.

Comment: In any case, what's the question here? What doesn't work? If there's no matching profile for an EmployeeID `profiles.Find` won't find anything. Just check for `null` and move to the next step. `regis.Find` seems to be using `employeeID` as an ID too. Is that correct?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  Ohh. But Why I'm getting null in profile object..?

Comment: Because there's no profile with that particular PK value? Do `profiles` and `regis` really use the same primary key values as employees? That would suggest there's a 1-1 relation between Employee and Profile/Regis

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos can you share any documentary to delete multiple tables with having parent childrelationship.?

Comment: If you simply google for `entity framework on delete cascade` you'll find a *lot* of results. First result should be [the docs themselves](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete). The link is from EF Core but the feature was in [EF 6 already](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/relationships#enabling-cascade-delete). Cascade Delete is the default for required relations in EF 6.

Comment: Which means, if you have an `Employee` object with `Profile` and `Regis` properties, you can probably just call `Remove(employee)` and EF will delete the related `Profile` and `Regis` entities. Check [Cascade Delete in EF 6](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/cascade-delete-in-code-first.aspx) too, it's probably clearer than the docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to include child table in parent object.

```
 [HttpPost]
         public ActionResult Delete(int id)
         {
            var parent = dbContext.regis.Include(p => p.profiles).SingleOrDefault(p => p.id == id);
            foreach(var child in parent.profiles.ToList())
            {
                dbContext.profiles.Remove(child);
                dbContext.SaveChanges();
            }
             return RedirectToAction("Index");
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion would be first, check to see you have that employee with Id you provided or not this is the easiest, i guess there MUST not be any! as you say it returns null.
are you getting this NULL for ALL inputs?

Second, try to run your code in debugger mode, put a break point at first line to see what EmployeeId is being sent to the Method. check it might be zero, so there is a problem in your POST method